# Ошибка System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down в WSL Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Настраиваю **gunicorn** и **nginx** для **django** проекта по этому гайду: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru.

При запуске сокета командой `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket` выдаётся ошибка:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

в WSL Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже настраивал по похожему гайду, день парился. В итоге оказалось что вместо команд systemctl надо использовать аналоги для Ubuntu на Windows

Systemd command = Sysvinit command

```
systemctl start service_name = service service_name start
systemctl stop service_name = service service_name stop
systemctl restart service_name = service service_name restart
systemctl status service_name = service service_name status
systemctl enable service_name = chkconfig service_name on
systemctl disable service_name = chkconfig service_name off
```

Т.е. ваша команда должна звучать как:

```
sudo service gunicorn.socket start
```

По той же самой схеме команда у меня выдает ошибку

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Но если переписать ее по другому работает

```
sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is running
```

Вот такие пироги. А во всех инструкциях пихают команды systemctl...

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, этот гайд не подходит.

В справке по [WSL Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL) говорится, что в этом варианте отсутствует `systemd`, вместо него используется другой `init` (о чем и сказано в тексте ошибки)

А так как `systemctl` является частью `systemd`, без него эта команда работать не будет.

Comment: Перед написанием ответа подумайте, чем он будет полезен. Пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с разделом помощи где вы сможете найти ряд полезных советов с помощью которых вы сможете написать действительно хороший ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Обычно эта проблема возникает при установке в версиях Ubuntu запущенных в wsl. Systemd стал поставляться в дистрибутиве из стора начиная с windows 11.

Для windows 10 systemd стал поставлять по умолчанию недавно. Необходимо либо отдельно включать systemd либо обновить wsl до последней версии

Попробуйте обновить в PowerShell командой

`wsl --update`